# Lost private key during eclipse upgrade

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, keystore

I updated the adt plugin for eclipse and it deleted the keystore that held my private key for my app that is already on the app store.  This was the only copy of the private key.  Is there any way to restore or rebuild this key for an update to the play store?

Comment: "This was the only copy of the private key" -- what about the backups of your development machine?

Comment: Indeed, you should look into some backup system. Or, even better, source control management. You can use Github for instance and commit your code to git.

Comment: Putting your private key on github? I don't think so...

Answer (score 2):

No.

Try to get some utilities that recover files on your computer and if you're lucky you can restore the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you lost the complete file, and not only the password; NO. You can't update this version of the app anymore, unfortunately. If you'd still have the file and not the password you might be able to run some kind of smart brute-force (still very unfeasible).

You could try some tools that recover deleted files though, but I can't help with that as I have no experience there.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to update your app in the Play Store without it being signed by the identical key, and there is NO way around this.

Your best hope is to somehow recover the keystore you used to sign your app.